# How do computers keep track of time?

Tags: time

How is time represented in the the computer? I mean doesn't the computer do all computations as fast as it can? How do you keep track of the passage of time if things run at various speeds on various machines?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock#Timing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Computers keep track of time they same way you or I do - with a clock!  The Real Time Clock runs even when the CPU is powered off.  It's completely separate from the "clock cycles" of the CPU.  On PCs, the clock runs on a battery when the computer is not plugged into an external power source.

Comment: how much battery can it retain?

Comment: @Matt If you're asking "how long can the clock last on one battery?" then the answer depends on the battery!  But generally, a headless quartz clock isn't very hungry and the battery will practically die of old age (shelf life) before it's drained.

Comment: thanks for responding on to my question, even nearly a year later, wow

Comment: @Matt, you are keeping track of time.

Answer (score 6):

So basically what happens is computers, microwaves, etc. usually use what is known as a quartz timer. The reason they use quartz is because when you give quartz crystal an electric charge, it vibrates and sends a pulse back (piezoelectricity). And since the crystals can be so finely shaped and cut, people can predict exactly how many pulses it will give in a second. So then once the computer reads that X number of pulses have happened, 1 second should be displayed. It then resets and starts reading again continually. If they wanted to, and in most cases they do, a separate processor knows that 60 seconds make a minute, or 60 minutes to and hour, so it then would display that it has been a minute/hour, and reset it's second timer. So both of the two processors do very similar things but just with different scales.

Answer (score 3):

In our desktop pc motherboard there is something known as **cmos battery** that keep track of our pc date and time even if it is shut down. **CMOS battery** has some life span until then it maintains and after that when ever you shut down and start your system your date and time will be reset..

Comment: @BobDalgleish The answers aren't just for the OP it's for everyone with the same question. In my opinion, new answers are always welcomed as sometimes one may be better than even the accepted answer years later.

Answer (score 2):

The electonic clock inside the computer can calculate the passing of time by using an oscillator which vibrates at a constant frequency. The clock then counts the number of vibrations to keep track of time.